# AngularJS UI-Router v1.0: getting state name during resolving

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, dependency-resolver

I am migrating from UI-Router v0.4.x to v1.0 and I'm having an issue. Consider the following piece of code.

```
myApp
    .component('myComponent', {
        bindings: {
            resolveBinding: '<'
        },
        controller: class myComponentController {
            constructor() {
                // ...
            }
        },
        templateUrl: someTemplateUrl
    })
    .config(($stateProvider) => {
        $stateProvider
            .state('some-state', {
                url: '/some-state',
                component: 'myComponent',
                resolve: {
                    resolveBinding: function(DependencyResolver) {
                        let targetStateName = this.self.name
                        return DependencyResolver.doSomeThingsFor(targetStateName)
                    }
                }
            })
    })
```

In the new version`let targetStateName = this.self.name` will fail because `this` is now `null`, whereas before it contained information on the state it was transitioning to.

How can I get the state name in this block of code?

I was thinking about using a `$transitions.onBefore` hook to put the name on `rootScope`, and doing something like:

```
resolveBinding: function($rootScope, DependencyResolver) {
    let targetStateName = $rootScope.hackyStateName 
    return DependencyResolver.doSomeThingsFor(targetStateName)
}
```

But I feel this is ugly and I'm missing out on something easier and more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject `$transition$` into a resolve function:

```
resolveBinding: function($transition$) {
  console.log($transition$.to());
}
```

See the [$transition$ documentation](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/injectables.html#_transition_).

Does that help you?

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. Thank you for pointing this out!